# How much damage do "Reflect Damage" creatures reflect?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does anyone know how reflect damage actually works?  Is it a set amount per difficulty?  A set percentage?  Some combination of the two?  Can life steal overcome the reflect damage enough that on average no life is lost or do the two stack in such a way the the reflected damage hits before the time-delayed life steal kicks in and it's still easy to kill yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience it is approximately 5%.  This was in Nightmare where some spell I was using on my wizard was doing about 700-odd damage and the ticks I was taking were in the high 30's.

[image]

From some of these shots:

- 104/1925? = 5.40%?
- 97/1838 = 5.28%
- 109/2070 = 5.27%
- 109/2073 = 5.26%

35.08% reduction from armor, 23.49% from arcane resist...

> 5.28% / ((1 - (35.08%)) * (1 - (23.49%))) = 10.63% *this seems strange...*

At that low amount, you're not in danger of wild swings up and down if you stack lifesteal.  That, or passive health regeneration could keep up with what you lose.

Comment: Very thorough, thanks!  In keeping with Sterno's comment from above, it would make sense if the armor damage reduction might have something to do with it.  Do you know what your damage reduction was for the above sequence?

Comment: @Palantar yeah, losing in LoL right now, Ill check when done

Comment: Why do you think it was arcane damage? (Is your arcane resist any different from other damage types?) Furthermore, are you using Blur?

Comment: I was using arcane orbs; figured it would reflect as arcane back to me (where oh where is the WoW combat log).  What's Blur?  The band?

Comment: @NickT Blur is a Wizard passive which reduces dmg take

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki:

> Thorns / Reflect Damage
>
> Monsters imbued with the Thorns trait, when hit with a melee attack,
>   return 20% of the damage dealt to them to the attacker.
>
> Min. Monster Level: 26.
>
> Available to: Rare, Champion (NOT minion).
>
> Damage Type: Standard.
>
> Additional Resistances: None.

Source: [Diablo Wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Traits_%28Diablo_III%29#Thorns_.2F_Reflect_Damage)

Comment: You must be able to apply damage reduction against the reflected damage, because when I'm laying into them with 20k or sometimes even 60k hits, I certainly don't seem to be hitting myself for 4k (or 12k!) each time.

Comment: I agree, I'd be murdering myself much quicker