# Reflect Damage Skills (Not Monster)

Tags: diablo-iii

Can someone explain how damage reflection works?

In other words: if a monster would normally hit for 100 and I have 20% damage reflect, which of these cases is true?

- monster takes 20, I take 100, then the 100 is reduced based upon stats
- monster takes 20, I take 80, then the 80 is reduced based upon stats
- 100 is reduced by stats results in `x`, I take `x` damage, monster takes .2(`x`) damage
- 100 is reduced by stats results in `x`, I take .8(`x`) damage, monster takes .2(`x`) damage

Comment: which skill reflects damage?  I only remember skills that reapply damage based on your weapon damage

Comment: @yx: Mantra of Retribution (monk aura) is one example.

Comment: hah, talk about missing that skill completely, and monk was the first class I got to 60 with.  Its pretty clear that reflection won't reduce the damage you take, so options 2 and 4 are out, but I don't know if its option 1 or 3, most likely option 3 based on the wording

Comment: If you find a mob you don't one shot, and that doesn't hurt you too quickly, then remove all of your +life per second/hit gear and put up your aura, with damage numbers and health bar numbers on you should be able to test it - it will be option 1 or 3 though, I am leaning towards it being #3.

Comment: Good thought. I am not able to test ATM and thought I'd ask. I will look a little at this myself later.

Comment: @ickleislands or as I like to call it, nekked act 1 testing.

Comment: In most games, damage reflect is done on the initial damage done by the mob, not damage taken by you. so 1st option is correct

Comment: Regardless, the monster likely doesn't take 20 damage...it likely takes 20 damage reduced by the monster's stats. Potentially it could be option 3 further reduced by the monster's stats, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @BrianColvin considering how much damage inferno monsters do pre reduction, it would make little sense to reflect initial damage, though it would make a pretty sick build if it worked because you'd be an absolute invincible tank/killing machine at the same time.  Hmm... I'll have to try it out on my monk later tonight.

Comment: @yx: this is why I am asking. If it worked that way, it would be viable (and scalable). If it reflects damage I already took, it is less enticing.

Comment: @yx Reflection != reduction.  It is important to note that first the total damage is done, then reduction modifiers(eg armor/resists or damage reduce) come into account.  If the mob has 20% damage reduction although the damage coming at him would be 20(from your reflection of his 100 hit) he would only take 16.

Comment: This has already been asked here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70016/how-much-damage-do-reflect-damage-creatures-reflect

Comment: That is the opposite of what I asked, and also it does not explain at what point the `x`% is taken. The point at which it happens is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. Monsters have their own stats (armor in particular). You take 100 base damage, reduced by your own stats. The monster takes 20 base damage, reduced by *their* stats.